# vsftpd, hide files users do not have prermission to

Tags: linux, ftp

My question is rather simple is it possible to config vsftpd so that it hides or not tell the client about file that the user have no permission to(No rwx) and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this, the deny_file and hide_file directives only work on file names not their permissions.

Answer (score 0):

By default the files you upload using ftp user will have permission to read, write or execute, but for example if the super user creates a file on ftp directory depending on the permissions of the file for example:

```
-rw-------  1 root      root          0 Aug 15 14:33 yourfile
```

Your ftp user won't be allowed to read, write or execute such file.

You could try by changing file permissions and ownership to some other user not included on your ftp user group

```
chmod 600 your-restricted-files
chown root.root your-restricted-files
```